# Can not find rMatClust parent point attribute

Tags: r, spatstat

Calling `rMatClust()` with parameter `saveparents=TRUE` is not providing with the parent point pattern in the result. How to retrieve the parent points?

I am trying something like the following:

`parent.kappa <- function(x,y){ exp(-8.944711 - 4.645625*10^(-5)*x -6.437164*10^(-4)*y)`

`simulated.ppp <- rMatClust(kappa=parent.kappa, scale=10, mu=5, nsim = 1, win=owin(c(0, 1000), c(0, 1000)), saveLambda=TRUE, saveparents=TRUE)`

According to the manual `simulated.ppp` should have an attribute named `parents` (a point pattern object) that holds the parent points of the Matern clusters.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Which version of  `spatstat` are you using? The current release is `1.64-1`

Comment: I updated to release ``1.64-1``, and found the ``parents`` attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem. When I run your example code using `spatstat 1.64-1`, the resulting point pattern `simulated.ppp` does have the desired attribute, `attr(simulated.ppp, "parents")`.

However, looking at the code for `rMatClust`, there is one special case where the result could be returned without the attribute `"parents"`. Namely, if the model parameters determine a point process with very weak clustering, then the code calls `rpoispp` to generate the result. Is it possible that you encountered this situation?

Please provide an example which demonstrates the problem.